# ADF - get random sample data from data flows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is it possible to get random sample data from data flows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sampling property provided in source setting in ADF is used to limit the records from the dataset. You can choose this when you have a large dataset. However, while you use debug to preview, row limit set in the `debug setting` will hold *preference* or is considered over Sampling row limit set.

I tried to verify and yes, it appears this is not the sampling as in context of getting random rows. There is no out of the box availability to get random rows from source in ADF. You would have to explicitly design a flow depending on the type of source data.

You can share a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)

Comment: I use **Trigger** (rather than debug) to execute Data flows. I set **Sampling Enable** and **Rows Limit to 10**, Data flows return top 10 row to me.